# Relative Path in Java for exporting csv-files

Tags: java, file, path, relative-path

I have developed a Java WebApp on a Windows System. It is a analytics program where the result set is being exported to csv File for Excel via export button.

Now the fact: I've hard coded the Path for the file to export to:

```
public String button1_action() {
   GenerateCSV  generateCSV = new GenerateCSV();

   Date zeitstempel = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("_dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss");

   generateCSV.generateCsvFile("h:/VR-Analyse-Tool_Excel Output" +simpleDateFormat.format(zeitstempel) +".csv", getSessionBean1().getExistingRightsList()); 

   return null;
}
```

that works fine on my local system.

Now I've deployed the `.war` file on an tomcat6 on a Linux System. Now this path is no longer working. Can somebody help me? I don't get how to solve this.

The program is for other users in my company who should be able to export the csv-file on their personal drive/space/amount on an server. Everybody has its own drive on this Server with the drive letter (h:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Strongly advice against writing the files in relative path , as this would be interpretted differently in different systems(OS)
The last thing you want is to debugging where the file got created

You could choose from any of the following approaches

1) Have the value declared in .properties file and read the value from the java program.
   this way when the environment changes , only need to edit the property file. So recompilation neccessary

2)Or better you could have this Db table and use it.

3) You can delare a Application context variable in Web.xml and use it

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
 <web-app>
   <context-param>
     <param-name>csv_file_path</param-name>
     <param-value>h:/your_file_path</param-value>
   </context-param>
 .
 .
 .
 .
</web-app>
```

Comment: Hi all, thx for your immediate response. I'll try it with the properties file. Sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
h:/VR-Analyse-Tool_Excel Output
```

use

```
/home/VR-Analyse-Tool_Excel Output
```

create a

```
h:/home
```

directory on your local machine and it should be working in both environments.

Answer (score 0):

Add your file path in web.xml when deploying in `Windows file(h:your_filepath) , Unix (home/your_filepath)`

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>downloadFilePath</param-name>
    <param-value>h:your_filepath</param-value>
  </context-param>
.
.
.
.
</web-app>
```

**Java code**

```
public String button1_action() {
   GenerateCSV  generateCSV = new GenerateCSV();
   String filepath =  getServletContext().getInitParameter("downloadFilePath");
   Date zeitstempel = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("_dd.MM.yyyy_HH.mm.ss");

   generateCSV.generateCsvFile(filepath  +simpleDateFormat.format(zeitstempel) +".csv", getSessionBean1().getExistingRightsList()); 

   return null;
}
```